# Why does Excel t-test return #DIV/0! error?

Tags: excel, t-test

I'm testing the `t.test` functionality of Excel and when I specify two-sided, paired with two lists of `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and `2,3,4,5,6,7,8`, paired t-test, the p-value returns #DIV/0! I have made sure the cell is formatted as number. As soon as I change the last number 8 of the second list to 9, the result becomes normal.

[image]

Comment: Swap any two numbers within their column...

Comment: The difference between every pair is the same. Can't compute paired t test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@Axel Richter`, the equation for paired student t-test has standard deviation of each paired difference in the denominator. since the difference between each pair is the same, the standard deviation is 0, which makes the denominator 0.